# JVisualVM - Profiler - agent jar loaded but agent failed to initialize

Tags: java, weblogic, jvisualvm

I'm trying to run a profiler with JVisualVM on a WebLogic Server, running: /u01/app/oracle/jdk/bin/./jvisualvm
but i'm getting the following error:

[image: JVisualVM error agent jar loaded but agent failed to initialize]

I ran with logging enabled: ./jvisualvm -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=../logging.properties

[image: JVisualVM log error]

How do i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be related to jvisualvm bug affecting jdk 7 and 8
https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8024453 
Check if you are using a fixed jdk version.
Fixed at 7u60 for jdk 7, 8b110 for jdk 8.
Or you can use java mission control, I think it is a superior profiler.

Comment: Hmm i'm using jdk 8_65, but i can't change the version right now. I tried to use JMC, but i couldn't find a profiler option. Is it related to flight recorder??

Comment: Yes, there is a nice explanation from Oracle in the link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qytuEgVmhsI

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the parameters on server start (-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder)